# Laravel 5.8 query scope

Tags: laravel, scope, laravel-5.8

I am learning laravel and I encountered this problem where when I use query scope my code returns zero data. The database has got data.
It is kinda confusing because I think I have done everything right as  per the tutorial

Scope:

```
public static function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::Latest();

    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: you should call scope with a small case in first character

Comment: $posts=Post::latest()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you won't be able to use `scopeLatest` as Laravel already has a [latest()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) method on its query builder.

---

As for the scope you tried to make, here are a few pointers:

- a `scope` shouldn't be defined as `static` method
- you shouldn't actually call `get()` inside your scope
- You don't need to return from the scope.

So even though this scope won't actually work (because of the name), as an example, this is what is would look like based on your question:

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('id', 'desc'); //desc should put the latest first
}
```

Your controller method (in either case) should be:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::latest()->get();

    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
}
```